# Elasticsearch java api get average of terms aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-java-api

I'm using elasticsearch with java api and I'm trying to get average value of lowest record from each bucket of term aggregation. One solution I found is to get results like this

```
AggregationBuilders.terms("group_by_flights").field("flight_id)
    .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.min("minimum").field("duration")))
```

and then count average on the code side. The problem is that if there will be lot of result, it will allocate a lot of memory to count it. I would like to do this on elastic side.
I found, that there is something like avg bucket pipeline aggregation, which can be add as **sibling** aggregation to terms (and others)

```
"the average": {
  "avg_bucket": {
    "buckets_path": "some_bucket_path" 
  }
}
```

Problem is that in java api you can add pipeline aggregation only as **subaggregation**. So if we construct our aggregation like this our terms aggregation won't be seen

```
AggregationBuilders.terms("group_by_flights").field("flight_id")
    .subAggregation(PipelineAggregatorBuilders.avgBucket("avg", "group_by_flights.duration" *<- this wont't be seen because its subaggregation*))
```

I was thinking about making some empty top aggregation and then add all aggregations as subaggregations, but it seems like silly walk-around, and I'm not understanding something correctly. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found so far is to make aggregations as sub aggregation of "empty aggregation"

```
AggregationBuilders.global("global_aggregation")
    .subAggregation((AggregationBuilders.terms("group_by_flights").field("flight_id"))
        .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.min("min").field("duration")))
    .subAggregation(PipelineAggregatorBuilders.avgBucket("avg_bucket_aggs","group_by_flights>min"))
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is use `FilterAggregationBuilder` to do it, this one can filtering data.The first sub aggregation to make data bucket, the second sub aggregation to merge bucket data.

```
AggregationBuilders.filter("global_aggregation", bool)
    .subAggregation((AggregationBuilders.terms("group_by_flights").field("flight_id"))
    .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.min("min").field("duration")))
    .subAggregation(PipelineAggregatorBuilders.avgBucket("avg_bucket_aggs", "group_by_flights>min"));
```